# Not able to find out Portable Class Libraries project in visual studio 2017 when creating cross platform app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-studio

Hi when i am going to create new xamarin forms app I'm not able to see Protable Class Library in the Sharing Code Strategy options in VS 2017 .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ulDY.png)

Please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior, it's no longer possible to create a PCL library with Visual Studio 2017 as they've been replaced by .NET Standard libraries, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard) for more details.

Also, the roadmap and the comparison with PCL profiles is available [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md), so you can determine the right .NET Standard version for you depending on your target framework and the APIs you need to place in the shared library.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Standard libraries are the replacement for Portable Class Libraries. They allow you access to more of the framework than pcl did.   You can still manually create a PCL project and reference it in a Xamarin app if you would like to use PCLs in new mobile apps with Xamarin.

Comment: But I saw a video article on Google, he is running visual studio professional 2017 and he was able to create PCL project under sharing code strategy can you tell me how

Comment: PCL option was replaced with standard libraries in visual studio 2017 versison 15.5 cross platform app

Comment: @NiteeshKumar Just trying to understand your reasoning here - this answer was posted half an hour later than mine, it came to the same conclusion and didn't include any links or resources about the new .NET Standard libraries, which you said you're not familiar with, and my answer used to be marked as valid up until a couple hours ago. Why has this replaced my answer as the valid answer for this question?

Comment: @Sergio0694, you both are correct, actually I am new in stack overflow and  I was trying to accept your both answer that's why

Comment: @NiteeshKumar Sure thing, no problem! 